# Jackson annotation to override the one in parent class

Tags: java, json, jackson, overriding, parent

I would like all my objects to have an ID and I wish to serialise it for some child class but not for some others

for example:

```
public class A {
  protected Long id;
  ..getter and setter
}

public class B extends A {

  @Override
  @JsonIgnore
  public Long getId() {..}

  @Override
  @JsonIgnore
  public void setId(Long id) {..}

}

public class C extends B {

  @Override
  @JsonInclude
  public Long getId() {..}

  @Override
  @JsonInclude
  public void setId(Long id) {..}
}

public class Test {

  Set<C> tests ...
  ..getter setter
}
```

I have tried serialising Test but the JSON string doesn't include the IDs
If I remove the JsonIgnore from B then in that case the Ids are there.

Is there a way with jackson to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
@JsonIgnore(false)
```

instead of

```
@JsonInclude
```