# Override value of custom runtime annotation applied on Interface

Tags: java, annotations, wildfly

**tl;dr: I'm overriding a method annotation of an interface on a child-child class, but the annotation's value is not being override.**

I'm surprised I didn't found the answer for this question on this or any other site, so I think it must be something wrong with my implementation, but I can't figure it out.

I have the following custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited //This only applies to class annotations, but I tried it anyway
public @interface MyRolesAllowed {
    String[] value();
}
```

And it's used on this interface:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface IRESTfulCRUDResource<T> {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @MyRolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public Response ws(@Context UriInfo uriInfo);
}
```

That's implemented as:

```
@Stateless
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public abstract class BaseCRUDResource<T> implements IRESTfulCRUDResource<T> {

    @Override
    public Response wsQuery(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        //...
    }
}
```

That I just override in this class to change the default annotation:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/something")
public class SomeResource extends BaseCRUDResource<Someclass> {
    @Override
    @MyRolesAllowed({"ADMIN", "USER"})
    public Response wsQuery(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        return super.wsQuery(uriInfo);
    }
}
```

This is all hosted on a Wildfly server, and I'm using the following interceptor to process the annotation:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        // I checked and at this point:
        // resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getSimpleName() == "SomeResource"

        String[] roles = resourceMethod.getAnnotation(MyRolesAllowed.class).value();

        // Now, I checked and at this point:
        // roles = {"ADMIN"}
        // In my understanding, it should be {"ADMIN", "USER"}, 
        // because I'm overriding the annotation on the child 
        // class, and resourceMethod points to the child method. 
        // What's wrong?
    }
}
```

So, as stated on the last comment, I was expecting the parent's annotation to be override by the child's one, but it's not happening. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37839796/3136474) is an example of annotation's value override.

I tried to use `resourceMethod.getAnnotationsByType` as well, but it provides the same values.

Am I misunderstanding something?

---

**Update:** as [@JohnBollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) pointed in the comments section, I checked and `resourceMethod.getDeclaringClass() == IRESTfulCRUDResource`, so it's counterintuitive but [ResourceInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html)'s `getResourceMethod` points to the parent method but `getResourceClass` points to the child class.

Comment: You have not established, as far as I can tell, that `resourceMethod` is a reference to the a `Method` declared by the child class.  Check its `declaringClass` property.

Comment: Overall, however, I think this approach is questionable.  If you annotate an abstract method, then, arguably, a differently annotated method does not *properly* override that method, even though Java accepts it as an override.  There are several thorny issues here; I recommend avoiding mixing method annotations with inheritance, or at least with polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, just checked and `resourceMethod.getDeclaringClass() == IRESTfulCRUDResource`, so it's counterintuitive but [ResourceInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html)'s `getResourceMethod` points to the parent method but `getResourceClass` points to the child class.